# Interference suppression coils for 9V DC adapter for audio equipment

Tags: dc, emc, coil, interference, emi-filtering

I am about to add voltage regulation to an unregulated 230V AC to 9V 150mA DC adapter, by adding an [L7809 voltage regulator](https://components101.com/regulators/7809-voltage-regulator-pinout-datasheet-specifications) and ceramic 0.33µF and 0.1µF capacitors.

I want to use this adapter to power a couple of (digital and analog) guitar effects pedals, but it was originally intended for use with a computer [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) interface, not (directly) with audio equipment, so I was wondering whether I should take additional precautions against interference, especially in the audio spectrum.

I had a look at 9V adapters made specifically for use with audio equipment, and e.g. the ubiquitous [Boss PSA-230S](https://www.thomann.de/be/boss_psa_230.htm) contains what is described as:

> High-quality interference suppression coils in extra housing

What type of coils would these be, and how would I choose the right ones to add to my project? Also, how important is it that these are added near the end of the DC cable, and not to the adapter itself?

[image: adapter (front)]
[image: adapter (back)]
[image: adapter (cover)]

<sup>The unregulated adapter as it is now. (click images to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: A 9V Bat or 9V Reg will not regulate a LM7809 the input must exceed the output and increases up to 2V with rated current.  use a Lithium battery and no regulator or just the Regulated 9V supply. Adding too much C may cause startup problems yet use low ESR caps near load if there are issues.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm sorry if the question is unclear, but I'm not talking about batteries but about a 230V AC to 9C DC adapter. Also, I'm an architectural, not an electrical engineer, so go easy on the acronyms and abbreviations :-)

Comment: The LM7809 regulator requires that the input voltage be at least 2 volts above the desired output voltage, so you need to start with an 11 or 12 volt supply.

Comment: @PeterBennett When I measured the output voltage without load, I got more than 14V, that's why I wanted to add voltage regulation in the first place. (The pedals I want to power with the adapter range from 6mA to 100mA, and I'm guessing different loads will lead to different voltages if the adapter remains unregulated.)

Comment: It says it is a switch mode stabilized supply 500mA, so it could be those cheap ones that need a 10% minimum load to be stable like 90’s vintage PC’s.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you talking about the Boss PSA230S? I only mentioned that as an example of an adapter specifically made for audio equipment. I've added some images of the adapter I'm working on to clear up any confusion.

Comment: ok yes that's the cheap old school "unregulated" supplies with 41% higher no load voltage which is the ratio of a peak rectified sine to average at rated load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power supply in the picture is a 9V unregulated linear power supply.

Because it is unregulated, it will output much more than 9V when unloaded, so your measurement of being more than 14V is perfectly fine.

And because it is a linear power supply, there is no high frequency noise you should be worried about.

Switch mode power supplies can have some noise on output, so that's why the other power supply you linked to has just standard noisy switch mode power supply and it needs the extra filtering to get rid of the noise.

Comment: Are you suggesting not to bother adding the voltage regulator either? One of the devices I want to power with the adapter is rated at just 6mA; will that not result in a voltage that is much higher than 9V?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. You especially need a 9V voltage regulator so you don't blow up a device with 14V. A linear voltage regulator does not add switching noise like a switch mode regulator does, so you don't need any extra filtering.